# xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" cannot be fetch by intellij

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am learning spring boot and there is a problem in my thymeleaf template.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div th:if="${message}">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When i fetch the external resource, there is an invalid URL exception saying: No XML at the specified location: http://www.thymeleaf.org

The dependency in maven is imported. I am using Intellij Community 2021.3.2

Comment: `http://www.thymeleaf.org` in that case is just a "name" (commonly resolved by your IDE) it has not the meaning as "schema location"/xsd uri

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue in IntelliJ and I fixed it with this solution:

1. Navigate to the following File > Settings > Plugins
2. From here you will search "ThymeLeaf" once you do "JBLHtmlToThymeLeaf" will come up
3. Install it
4. Then go to your HTML file, right click it and select "JBLHtmlToThymeleaf"

This will add `namespace(xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org")` attribute to HTML tag.